# How to add PATHs for readPDF{tm}

Tags: r, pdf, tm

I am struggling with readPDF command from 'tm' package.  When I run the following command:

```
docsPDF <- Corpus(DirSource(cnames), readerControl = list(reader=readPDF))
```

Above command gives the following error:

```
Error in system2("pdftotext", c(control$text, shQuote(x), "-"), stdout = TRUE): 
'"pdftotext"' not found
```

This is because "pdfinfo" and "pdftotext" files of XPDF are not present in the R System.

```
file.exists(Sys.which(c("pdfinfo", "pdftotext")))
FALSE FALSE
```

I was just wondering how can I add paths of these two files in R system (under Win8)? Thanks!

Comment: Is this windows?  If so you need to put them on your path.

Comment: Yes, I am running Windows 8, and I have added them in my environmental variables as following:
Variable Names: pdfinfo
Variable Values: C:\Program Files\xpdf\bin64\pdfinfo.exe
Variable Names: pdftotext
Variable Values: C:\Program Files\xpdf\bin64\pdftotext.exe

Do I need to add them on some other path as well?

Comment: I would just append the two paths to the already existing PATH.

Comment: I have just added path as C:\Program Files\xpdf\bin64 and it is running fine... Thanks